# Javascript Special Character removal not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have written a jsp code with values coming from other jsp and i need to remove the special characters in the string.But iam not able to remove special characters. Please help

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
       <script>
            function change(chars){
                var dchars=document.getElementById("chars").value;
                dchars = dchars.replaceAll("!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>?", '');
            document.getElementById("chars").innerHTML=dchars;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
   <%
String res=request.getParameter("tes");
       %>
       <body onload="change(chars)" ><script>
        change(res)
</script>
     <div id="chars"> <%=res%></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "value" for div elements. You need to use innerHtml insted:

```
document.getElementById('chars').innerHTML = dchars;
```

Comment: Still it doesnt remove special characters

Comment: You also have a bug in your body onload statement. Renmove the unnecessary "chars" attribute! And you are not using it in you rfunction either, so why have it there?

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
 document.getElementById('chars').innerHTML = dchars; //div has no value..
```

Assuming by special characters, you mean anything that's not letter, here is a solution:

```
alert(dchars.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

OR

```
alert(dchars.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')); //will filter the string down to just alphanumeric values
```

Comment: it must also have numbers and characters but no special characters

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using innerHTML is that certain characters are automatically converted to HTML entities such as `&` which is converted to `&amp;`

```
function cleanCharsText(){

    var el = document.getElementById("chars");
    var txt = el.innerText || el.textContent;
    el.innerHTML = txt.replace( /[!@#$%^&*()+=\\[\]\';,/{}\|\":<>\?]/gi, '');
}
```

However if you have the following `<span> text </span>` inside your chars element the html span tags will be removed when you run the above function as we are only extracting the text.